# Color icon disappeared after update in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I just made the 2016.1 update of PhpStorm.

It works well, but before I had the preview of the color on the left margin in css documents and now I can't see the color any more...

Any idea how can I get it back? It is a lovely feature!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151485) that is fixed already. Next update (v2016.1.1.) will contain the fix.

Right now you may try increasing/decreasing the editor font size for the color boxes to re-appear (apparently they are linked).